# Winform application crashs on WINDOWS 7 -64bits

Tags: c#, windows-7, crash, 64-bit

I have a huge problem on one of my winform application. Someone who use my application works on windows 7 64bits and apparently it directly crashes when the application is launching.

My application works correctly on :

-Windows XP

-Windows Vista

-Windows 7 (32bits).

I developped the application on Visual C# express 2005 (.NET 2.0).

I am wondering if there is anything I can do to recompile my application to make it work on windows 7 64bits.

I am sorry, I have no access to the computer of the person (so I can't check, exception or anything like that). I am pretty sure that this issue is known that's why I'm asking you right now.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you by advance for your Help

Regards,

Joze

Comment: are you trying to access some resources like : Registry, Program files files, System32 files ?

Comment: Yes, for program file files (in x32 aswell) so I run the application as Admin and it works for now.

Answer (score 2):

In project ***properties setting window***, select tab ***Build*** and change ***Platform target*** to **X86**. Republish..

**EDIT: to the down-voter**
By doing this Windows will know your program is designed for X86 use and will install it accordingly. (I've done this with Clickonce, and it works..)

Comment: That's not a good idea to change your build to `x86` if it's not working on `x64`... You've better try to change it to `Any`

Comment: .. have you tried? anyway, this is my solution for my users with 64bit platform and it works without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Likly you use some interop x86 DLL or COM object. Try setting for your executable Target Platform x86 (not Any CPU as it is by default).

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any unmanaged (com) components in your application?

If so, most likely you're including the 32bit version. If that's the case, you will have to compile 2 different versions of your program, one including the 32bit components, and the other including the 64bit components.

If that's not the case, it means you're using some platform specific code somewhere. More details about your application could help clarify the problem.